# conflict using "this". how to access a variable outside a method in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm learning Angular 6 and I'm trying to do some super dummy stuff.

I'm trying to replicate this JS code in Angular:

```
var x;

function go(){
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json =>{
    x = json;
    console.log(x)
  } )
}

go();
```

And I can successfully assign the returned value to the x variable and print it.

However, when I try to do the same in angular, I can not assign the value returned within the promise to the external property. (I get undefined when I try to print it)

This is how I tried to transform the above JS code to Angular syntax without luck:

```
import { Component, AfterContentInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  obj;

  go() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json =>{
      this.obj = json;
  })
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.go();
    console.log(this.obj) // undefined
  }
}
```

Does it have to do with the `this` keyword? Is the problem that "this" refers to the `go()`  method? If so, how can I point to the obj property of the class from within the promise? I'm so lost.

Thanks.

Comment: `this.go();` is asynchronous call, thus undefined.

Comment: Do the same in Angular as you do in your JS example: move `console.log(this.obj)` inside of the promise callback, in the `go` method.

Comment: but, isn't there a way to really modify the obj variable from within the promise?

Comment: The problem is the asynchronous call. You can also implement async/await or wrapping your go method inside a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `console.log` will actually execute before `this.go()` finishes.

But your function `this.go()` is working fine and `this.obj` will actually be modified but only after `fetch` finishes and return with it's data `response.json()` which again happens after `console.log`.

To make sure that your logic runs after `fetch` finishes you have to write your logic inside the promise callback function as follows.

```js
import { Component, AfterContentInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  obj;

  go() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json =>{
      this.obj = json;
      console.log(this.obj) // runs after `fetch` finishes and will log the modified value.
  })
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.go();
    console.log(this.obj) // this will run before `this.go()` you have to wait for it to finish.
// result is undefined
  }
}
```

To better understand Promises I suggest this [post](https://javascript.info/promise-basics)